# Magento 2 - CMS Pages, Blocks and Layouts

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-2.0, cms

I am fairly new to Magento, I read trough the documentation and everything I could find explaining the frontend developement process. But I still do not get some of the basics.

Here is a simple layout of a single page ("Home" for example):

[image]

I get that I configure the parts of my layout which are constant for every page in my default.xml (in this case the header, footer and a container for my main content)

But what I don´t get:

1. Do I create a seperate layout (.xml) for every single page even if my content blocks and the content inside of them are the only thing that is changing?
2. Or do I create blocks via the backend, put those blocks inside of a widget and assign that widget to a page?
3. Or do I put my content directly into the page? (via the content tab in backend->pages->home->Content)